# How to force reloading webview resources (ignore webview cache) every time opening?

Tags: caching, react-native, webview

I find it instantly opening the webview page from cache after the first load. And it can't see the updated content on the webview page.

=== Edit ====

**My webview code**

The `subModuleUrl` may be a static html or pure domain

```js
render() {
    const { subModuleUrl } = this.props   // the webview url, like: http://a.example.url.com/index.html
    const { isWebViewLoadFails } = this.state

    return (
      <View style={ApplicationStyles.screen.mainContainer}>
        {
          isWebViewLoadFails ?
            <View style={styles.errorShow}>
              <Text>Load fail</Text>
            </View>
            :
            <WebView
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              startInLoadingState={false}
              ref={webview => { this.webview = webview }}
              source={{ uri: subModuleUrl }}
              javaScriptEnabled
              injectedJavaScript={WebViewBridge}
              onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
              automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
              onMessage={this.handleMessage}
              onLoadStart={this.onWebViewLoadStart}
              onError={this.onErrorLoad}
              scalesPageToFit={false}
              domStorageEnabled
            />
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Please provide your WebView code

Comment: WebView code provided

Comment: May be it's related to your injectedJs. I found same issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11581

Comment: Thanks. But is not that issue

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Did you find any solution, i am facing same problem